# Toggle one element and add class to another element jquery

Tags: jquery

I have left-side menu for mobile users. It should open on click on `img#mobile-menu`

I wrote such code

```
(function() {
    $("#img#mobile-menu").removeClass("active");
    $("img#mobile-menu").toggleClass("active");
    if ($("img#mobile-menu").hasClass("active")) {
        $("#mobile-menu-sidebar").addClass("active");
    } else {
        $("#mobile-menu-sidebar").removeClass("active");
    }
}());
```

Problem is that when I open / refresh page both elements #mobile-menu and #mobile-menu-sidebar already has active class, but they shouldn't have it till I click img#mobile-menu

Comment: do it on click event of the menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("#mobile-menu").toggleClass("active");
$('#mobile-menu').click(function() {
  $("#mobile-menu").toggleClass("active");
  if ($("#mobile-menu").hasClass("active")) {
    $("#mobile-menu-sidebar").addClass("active");
    $('span').text("mobile-menu-sideba has active ")
  } else {
    $("#mobile-menu-sidebar").removeClass("active");
    $('span').text("mobile-menu-sideba has remove active ")
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='mobile-menu'>mobile-menu</button>
<span></span>
```

Do it no click event

Comment: tried your variant. but when I refresh page img#mobile-menu already has class active

Comment: remove that line before click event

Answer (score 0):

have the first line of your function disable/remove-active from both elements:

```
$("#img#mobile-menu,#mobile-menu-sidebar").removeClass("active");
```

Comment: thank you. didn't try your example as used another one